# ASP.NET CORE - Get API URL

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I get my API URL (only API URL).

In development mode `https://localhost:44372/`

In production mode: `https://{{ server api url }}`

This is because I want to store full path file in Database some like this:

```
https://localhost:44372/files/licenceFiles/1234.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on where you configure your production Url. There are roughly half a dozen places, where you can store them out of the box.

LazZiya has given you an approach that works just fine locally, but hits some limitations, once you exceed the scenario, where there is only dev and prod.

If you configure them in your appsettings.json *and* as an environment variable, the environment variable take have precedence. If your app is going to be containerized, chances are, that most of these values will be set using einvironment variables.

To read those use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_URLS")`, which would give you the internal urls Kestrel is listening on. public addresses, will probably have a different key - but you get the idea.

You can read up on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Ok, but there is no HttpContext.GetUrl or some like this?

Comment: You can get the requst path from http context: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.path?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

Define both URL's in `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
    "ApiUrl_local": "https://localhost:xxx",
    "ApiUrl_web": "https://website.com";
}
```

Then use `IWebHostEnvironment` to check for development mode and retrive the relevant setting:

```cs
public class ApiConfig
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public ApiConfig(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration
    }

    public string ApiURL => Environment.IsDevelopment() ? 
    Configuration["ApiUrl_local"] : Configuration["ApiUrl_web"];
}
```

Comment: While this may work locally, it will become tedious to use, once you containerize the application and use it in multiple stages (test, user acceptance, dev prod, ...). Personally I'd prefer a configuration over Environment variables, which you can set using build variables in your container image

Comment: @Marco yes you are right, I just used a simple usecase :)

Comment: No worries. Up to the OP to decide, if the approach is feasible for his scenario.

Comment: There is no HttpContext.GetUrl or some like this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used the follwing:

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;
    private string _serverPath;

    public CustomerLicenceFilesService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
        _serverPath = $"{_httpAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{_httpAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host}";
    }
```

Comment: Well, someone put unlike, but I already use this and its working in several environments.

Comment: I appreciate! This really helped me, @Marcelo:
`var url = $"{_httpAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{_httpAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host}";`.